# C# Inherited Class looks for Base Class Functions

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a couple different modeless forms that i recently inherited from a class i call Popup_Base. Basically, this just contains some events and variables that i use to get data back from a modeless form and allows me to pass a general calss to another helper class that i use to open these windows. Anyway, the problem is that for a particular Class that inherits off of this Popup_Base, it throws errors looking for Top Level functions in the Base Class. For example, a Calendar inherits off of the Popup_Base class and contains functions like Date_Click. However, the compiler throws an error saying that it cannot find it. Something like this:

```
"Error  1   'Popup_Base' does not contain a definition for 'monthCalendar1_DateSelected' and no extension method 'monthCalendar1_DateSelected' accepting a first argument of type 'Popup_Base' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
```

I get a similar error

```
"Error  5   'Popup_Base.InitializeComponent()' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

"

I wont post my entire code, but the Popup Class looks like this:

```
public partial class Popup_Base : Form
{
    public event EventHandler<NameUpdatedEventArgs> FirstNameUpdated;
    protected Control m_ctrl;
    protected virtual void OnFirstNameUpdated(NameUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (FirstNameUpdated != null)
            FirstNameUpdated(this, e);
    }

    protected int? m_row;
    protected int? m_col;

    public void Set_Sender_Info(Control Ctrl, int? Row = null, int? Col = null)
    {
        m_ctrl = Ctrl;
        m_row = Row;
        m_col = Col;
    }
}
```

(The names of this were taken from a tutorial)

Then, here is a sample calendar

```
public partial class form_Calendar : Popup_Base
{
    //
    public form_Calendar(int ix, int iy, Calendar_Display_Mode Type = Calendar_Display_Mode.Day, Control Sender = null, int? row = null, int? col = null)
    {
        if (Type == Calendar_Display_Mode.Month)
            //monthCalendar1.selection
            x = ix;
        y = iy;
        //this.Location = new Point(
        InitializeComponent();
        // this.Location = new Point(x, y);

    }
}
```

I feel like this is something really stupid that im missing.

Comment: InitializeComponent() is private, call it in the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that is true, because your `PopupBase` indeed doesn't have a method called `monthCalendar1_DateSelected`. (It is most likely expected in the `PopupBase.Designer.cs` file. You must have double clicked the `monthCalendar` control and just removed the method, not the event handler registration.)

The error about `InitializeComponent` is probably true if you want to derive a class that is built with the designer. The `InitializeComponent` is most likely `private` in `PopupBase`, you have to make it `protected` to work, or only call the method from `PopupBase`, which seems to make more sense.

Comment: If i have a designer file for the Calendar but not for the Popup_Base, will i still need to call the base class InitializeComponent?

Comment: Are you sure you have no designer file? The `InitializeComponents` method *does* exist, it's not accessible.

Comment: the problem is that the Calendar has those functions but the base doesnt. How do i ensure that it looks for the top level functions instead of the bottom?

Comment: Don't reference them, or if you need them in the base class, but define them in the derived class: create a `virtual` or `abstract` method.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.icomponentconnector.initializecomponent(v=vs.110).aspx - shows that `initializeComponent` is an interface implementation, meaning it *has* to be a public method... If the original signature has been hidden by a new method, then we'll definitely have problems.

Comment: Yes, there is no designer file. There really shouldnt be. All that class does is add a few extra pieces of data in between the Form Class and the designed class (Like a calendar)

Comment: Finally figured it out. Turns out that somehow the Class name in the designer file had changed to Popup_Base. Patrick was right. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @code4life: No, it doesn't. And by the way, you are referencing WPF, not WF.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the variable `monthCalendar1` seems to be `Popup_Base`. And `Popup_Base` does not know anything about methods that are only present in derived classes. Imagine the following derived class:

```
public partial class form_Calendar : Popup_Base
{
    public void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

In that case you cannot call `monthCalendar1_DateSelected` on variables of type `Popup_Base`:

```
Popup_Base popup = new form_Calendar();
popup.DateSelected += popup.monthCalendar1_DateSelected; // <-- error!
```

You must call it on a variable of the derived type:

```
form_Calendar calendar = new form_Calendar();
calendar.DateSelected += calendar.monthCalendar1_DateSelected; // <-- this works!
```

If you have only a `Popup_Base` variable you can cast to the derived type:

```
Popup_Base popup= new form_Calendar();
form_Calendar calendar = (form_Calendar)popup;
calendar.DateSelected += calendar.monthCalendar1_DateSelected; // <-- this works!
```

Comment: Good answer. It turned out to be a stupid error in that my designer file was somehow defined as the PopupBase class instead of the Calendar. But this would have lead me right to it.